# Windows Run Time GetFileFromPathAsync Not Returning

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am hoping someone can shed some light on a problem I am having. I am writing a Windows Store app which on startup needs to copy a "seed" database from the App installation folder `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path` to the Local data folder `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`. To do this I have used the following called from my `OnNavigatedTo` method in `Main()`.

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Calls  method in Dal Class which ensures database is in correct location and if not copies it
    Dal.LoadData();  

    RefreshScenarioList();
    ScenarioList.SelectedIndex = 0;  //this is the Default Item             
}

public static async void LoadData()
{
    await CopyIfNotExists(dbName);
}

private static async Task CopyIfNotExists(string dbName)
{
    if (await GetIfFileExistsAsync(dbName) == null)
    {

        StorageFile seedFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(
        Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path,
        dbName));

        await seedFile.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
}

private static async Task<StorageFile> GetIfFileExistsAsync(string key)
{
    try
    {
        return await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(key);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException) { return default(StorageFile); }
}
```

Please also note that I have also used `GetFileAsync` and also tried using a uri to obtain the seed file (to see if there was any difference). With the combination here I seem to be having the highest success rate. This seems to work 2-3 times out of every 4 tries but I would be much more comfortable with something that works 100% of the time. It only needs to copy the database once on startup.

When it doesn't work it "seems" to never return (ie `CopyIfNotExists` never seems to complete). The issue appears to be in the `CopyIfNotExists` method. The problem is that virtually the next line of code in my `OnNavigatedTo` method is a query on the database and it falls over when the database doesn't copy.

Any insights that anyone may have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your app targeting Windows 8, 8.1, 10? Also please edit your question and add your `OnNavigatedTo()` method.

Comment: Have you tried turning on first-chance exceptions? If anything goes wrong during the `await` you will miss it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I originally wrote it for Windows 8.1 under the windows 8.1 OS however figured given it was based on the Windows Run Time that it would work ok on Windows 10. The Windows store folk made it available for Wndows 8.1 and windows 10. I have since upgraded to Windows 10 ...thought that may have caused some odd permissions issue with the App installation directory. I will add my On Navigated to method to the  question.

Comment: I am also attempting an alternative approach which i was originally going to do anyway which is create the DB in script and insert the seed records in code. If this works ok then I will close this...although I will still try and work out what the issue is. I will give 1st chance exceptions a try to see if it enlightens me. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the problem here is that your use of `async` and `await` does not go as far up the call stack as it can.

When writing async code, there are a couple of general rules to follow -

1. If a function `Foo` uses the `async` keyword, then any other function that calls `Foo` must also use the `async` keyword.
2. Never use `async void` in a function signature - use `async Task` instead. The exceptions are:

   - your function is an event handler (e.g. button press)
   - or you are overriding a method that happens to return `void`

Let's take a look at the method signatures on your call stack. `OnNavigatedTo` is shown here at the top:

```cs
      override void              OnNavigatedTo()
async          void              LoadData()
async          Task              CopyIfNotExists()
async          Task<StorageFile> GetIfFileExistsAsync()
```

The bottom two methods of the call stack uses `async Task` in the method signatures. Above those on the call stack is `LoadData`, which follows rule 1 above, but breaks rule 2.  `LoadData` should be changed to this:

```cs
public static async Task LoadData()
{
    await CopyIfNotExists(dbName);
}
```

Next we try to make `OnNavigatedTo` follow the above rules:

```cs
async protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

Note that we cannot use `async Task`, since your method is an override. We have to stick to `async void`.

Now you just need to add `await` to your `LoadData` call since it is an `async` method.  We do this so that your program waits for `LoadData` to complete prior to calling `RefreshScenarioList`:

```cs
async protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Calls  method in Dal Class which ensures database is in correct location and if not copies it
    await Dal.LoadData();  

    RefreshScenarioList();
    ScenarioList.SelectedIndex = 0;  //this is the Default Item             
}
```

Now you will want to also ensure that the call stack for `RefreshScenarioList` follows the async rules above.

---

One more thing that I noticed with your code. In Windows 8.1 or later, you should use [TryGetItemAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) instead of `GetFileAsync`:

```cs
private static async Task<StorageFile> GetIfFileExistsAsync(string key)
{
    return await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(key) as StorageFile;
}
```

The new method returns `null` when it cannot find a file. The old method throws an exception. Throwing exceptions on a UI thread can cause your UI to stall, so it is advantageous to use the new method.

Comment: Thanks chue x that fixed the issue and clarified for me a couple of points on the correct imlplementation of async and await. Thanks again.